# ecto - set field in intermediate table in many to many relationship

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have two entities Users and Rooms with a many to many relationship.

I've added an additional field `permission`to the intermediate table

Migration:

```
 def change do
    create table(:room_users) do
      add :permission, :string
      add :user_id, references(:users)
      add :room_id, references(:rooms)
    end

    create unique_index(:room_users, [:user_id, :room_id])
  end
```

Schemas:

```
 schema "rooms" do
    field :name, :string
    many_to_many :users, User, join_through: "room_users"

    timestamps()
  end

...

  schema "users" do
    field :username, :string
    many_to_many :rooms, Room, join_through: "room_users"
    timestamps()
  end
```

I've written a changeset that associates a user with a room, which works

```
  def changeset_update_user(room, user) do
    room
    |> cast(%{}, [:name])
    |> validate_required([:name])
    |> put_assoc(:users, [user])
  end
```

Now the question: whenever I associate a user to a room I also want to set the permission field.
Something like

```
  def changeset_update_user(room, user) do
    room
    |> cast(%{}, [:name])
    |> validate_required([:name])
    |> put_assoc(:users, [%{user_id: user.id, permission: "HOST"}])
  end
```

EDIT: function to associate user with room

```
  def create_Room_with_User(attrs \\ %{}, user) do
    {result, room_dto} = %Room{}
                    |> Room.changeset(attrs)
                    |> Repo.insert()

    Repo.preload(room_dto, :users)
    |> Room.changeset_update_user(user)
    |> Repo.update()

    {result, room_dto}
  end
```

But then I get an error that user_id and permission are unknown fields

Comment: `put_assoc(:room_users, …` should work.

Comment: I get `cannot put assoc room_users, assoc room_users not found`. I've added the function to add a user to rooms in my thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an `unknown field :permission` because this is not a `User` field, but a `RoomUser` field.

As explained in the docs, [`many_to_many/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#many_to_many/3-using-ecto-assoc-2) is a convenience when you don't need to care about the intermediate table: since you need `permission`, this is not the case.
Quoting the doc:

> If you need to access the join table, then you likely want to use `has_many/3` with the :through option instead.

The idea is described [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3-has_many-has_one-through).

Translated in your example, this becomes:

```elixir
defmdoule Room do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "rooms" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :room_users, RoomUser
    has_many :users, through: [:room_users, :user]
  end
end

defmodule User do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :room_users, RoomUser
    has_many :rooms, through: [:room_users, :room]
  end
end

defmodule RoomUser do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "room_users" do
    field :permission, :string
    belongs_to :user, User
    belongs_to :room, Room
  end
end
```

You can then replace your `put_assoc` with:

```elixir
|> put_assoc(:room_users, [%{user: user, permission: "HOST"}])
```